# How to stub :where method in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, stub

I have following code:

```
Group.where('name ~* ?', params[:name]).first
```

How to stub `where` method in that case?

```
Group.stub(:where).and_return(mock_model(Group, name: "SomeName"))
```

causes error:

```
Mock "Group_1001" received unexpected message :first with (no args)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, you should return somethings that responds to `first`. Array is a good choice.

```
Group.stub(:where).and_return([mock_model(Group, name: "SomeName")])
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `stub_chain` to stub both `where` and `first` and then return your object:

```
Group.stub_chain(:where, :first).and_return(mock_model(Group, name: "SomeName"))
```